# Openshift application got error

Tags: openshift

I was created a PHP 5.4 application with Web load balancer and mysql 5.5 support on openshift free plan. My problem is when I login into my app via SSH delete the index.php file in app-root/runtime/repo folder (Openshift web folder) and create new test.txt file, my application doesnt show test.txt file. It still shows Openshift welcome page when I access my application.Then I delete test.txt file. The app-root/runtime/repo folder is empty. I tried create new file name 'blahblah' in runtime folder and access but still nothing, only 404 page. However, restart the application doesn't resolve the problem! The problem only happend when I add 'Web Load Balancer'. Without load balancer, my PHP app working normaly event I delete index.php file

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "Web Load Balancer", it runs in front of your application and monitors which of your web servers are up and running.  You can visit http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status to view the status of your backend servers.  If nothing responds at the root context (/) of your application on the web servers, the haproxy thinks it is down and takes it out of rotation.  You have to have something (even a blank index.php or index.html) page so that the haproxy will get a status 200, or change the url that is monitored in the haproxy.cfg file on your main gear.

Comment: Thanks,
I put another index.php file and it work. But when I change the numbers of gears from 1 to 2 (default set to 1), it return 404 error again. Also in haproxy-status shows new column name "gear-xx...-mydomain" (before only local-gear) what is that column?Thanks,
I put another index.php file and it work. But when I change the numbers of gears from 1 to 2 (default set to 1), it return 404 error again. Also in haproxy-status shows new column name "gear-xx...-mydomain" (before only local-gear) what is that column?

Comment: That is because scaling only works correctly if you are uploading your files via git (not sftp), if you are using ssh to create a new file, it does not get copied to the new gear when it is created.

Comment: How to resolve this problem,I alway upload files via Ssh?

Comment: You can't.  If you want the scaling to work correctly use the git workflow.